# Program crashes when using std::bitset but only when compiled with VC 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std-bitset

I'm working on a simple program which converts strings into binary code and back. I'm working on Ubuntu and wanted to compile the program on Windows with Visual Studio 2015. While the Linux build runs fine, on Windows it compiles, but crashes with something like

```
bitset<N> char
```

when calling following function:

```
bool bin2string(std::string *psBinaryString, std::string *psCharakterString)
{
psCharakterString->clear();
char cTempArray[8];
char cTemp;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < psBinaryString->length(); i += 8)
{
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        cTempArray[j] = psBinaryString->c_str()[j + i];
    }
    std::bitset<8> Bitset(cTempArray);
    cTemp = static_cast<char>(Bitset.to_ulong());
    psCharakterString->push_back(cTemp);
}
return true;
}
```

Now, my questions are, what is wrong with this code? Why does it work on Linux (gcc) and Windows (MinGW), but not on Windows with Visual Studio 2015?

My current workarround for this is:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

bool bin2string(std::string *psBinaryString, std::string     *psCharakterString)
{
psCharakterString->clear();
char cTempArray[8];
char cTemp;

for(size_t i = 0; i < psBinaryString->length(); i += 8)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        cTempArray[j] = psBinaryString->c_str()[j + i];
    }
    cTemp = static_cast<char>(strtol(cTempArray, 0, 2));
    psCharakterString->push_back(cTemp);
}
return true;
}

#else

bool bin2string(std::string *psBinaryString, std::string *psCharakterString)
{
psCharakterString->clear();
char cTempArray[8];
char cTemp;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < psBinaryString->length(); i += 8)
{
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        cTempArray[j] = psBinaryString->c_str()[j + i];
    }
    std::bitset<8> Bitset(cTempArray);
    cTemp = static_cast<char>(Bitset.to_ulong());
    psCharakterString->push_back(cTemp);
}
return true;
}

#endif
```

Which one of these two solutions is better?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? What actually happens?

Comment: According to the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset bitset's constructor expects a null-terminated string when the array length is not specified. You are lucky this works at all on linux.

Comment: @Frank The answer box is below.

Comment: *Why does it work on Linux (gcc) and Windows (MinGW), but not on Windows with Visual Studio 2015?*  -- You're lucky Visual Studio 2015 crashed, indicating you had a silent error in the Linux version. -- *My current workarround for this is:* -- No, don't do "workarounds".  Whenever a compiler that is used by thousands of programmers around the world crashes with basically simple code, there is an error in your program, not a "bug" in the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Your crash is caused by the fact that std::bitset's constructor expects either an array length, or a null terminated string.

(see the documentation at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset)

So you should be using:

```
std::bitset<8> Bitset(cTempArray, 8);
```